# if checkbox checked changed, change class on td

Tags: php, jquery

I want only td (Test 1) change class(yellow).
How to make only td (Test 1) change color (not entire row).

```js
$('input[name="cek"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('yellow', $(this).is(':checked'));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checked[name="cek"]').closest('tr').addClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nowrap>TGL</th>
      <th>CEK</th>
      <th>TITEL</th>
      <th>VAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01.12.19</td>
      <td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
      <td nowrap>Test 1</td>
      <td nowrap>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try `closest('td')` instead of `closest('tr')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```js
$('input[name="cek"]').on('change', function() {$(this).closest('td').next('td').toggleClass('yellow',$(this).is(':checked'));});
```

```css
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th nowrap>TGL</th>
<th>CEK</th> 
<th>TITEL</th>
<th>VAL</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>01.12.19</td>
<td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
<td nowrap>Test 1</td>
<td nowrap>1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parent()` with `next()`.

```js
$('input[name="cek"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent().next('td').toggleClass('yellow', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nowrap>TGL</th>
      <th>CEK</th>
      <th>TITEL</th>
      <th>VAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01.12.19</td>
      <td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
      <td nowrap>Test 1</td>
      <td nowrap>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do something below**

```js
$('input[name="cek"]').on('change', function() {
   // $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('yellow',$(this).is(':checked'));
$(this).parents('td').siblings("td:eq(1)").toggleClass('yellow',$(this).is(':checked'));

});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:checked[name="cek"]').closest('tr').addClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th nowrap>TGL</th>
<th>CEK</th> 
<th>TITEL</th>
<th>VAL</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>01.12.19</td>
<td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='cek' /></td>
<td nowrap>Test 1</td>
<td nowrap>1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```